# Incorporating Joomla's RokAjaxSearch into Blogger?

Tags: php, joomla, blogger, rokajaxsearch

I want to incorporate a RokajaxSearch into the fixed header of my blogger site.

I've googled different queries on this to no avail.
Is it possible to add rokajaxsearch to a blogger site? and if so, how would one go about setting it up? so it lists results for posts in my blogger.

I don't think I can upload those files to blogger. so I was thinking I could upload the js, css files to another host that direct to my blogger site, not sure though. My site gets 3.5K views a day. I want to really up the game in the functionality of the site.

Little stuck here..Thanks in advance for any coding advice guys.

Answer (score 1):

You will firstly need to import the Joomla framework like so:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../' ); // should point to Joomla root - change accordingly
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Then to display the module, you can use the following:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'rokajaxsearch', 'Search' );
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs );
```

For more information on how to render a Joomla module, have a read of this:

http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/renderModule

Hope this helps

Comment: What would I put for the joomla root? and in blogger html where would I paste that first piece of coding? would it be under a <script>? I tried placing it under <head> to no avail. Thank you very much for your help!